# changing scene in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

what's the matter with this code?
i'm relly confused!!
i wanted to change my scene in main stage.

```
public class SignInController {
    @FXML
    TextField SignInPassword;

    @FXML
    TextField SignInUsername;

    @FXML
    CheckBox RememberMe;

    public void signUpScene(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws IOException {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        Scene SignUpScene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sign up.fxml")),700,700);
        Main.pstage.setScene(SignUpScene);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,new KeyValue(SignUpScene.getWidth(),0.0 )),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000.0d),new KeyValue(SignUpScene.getWidth(),700.0 ) )
        );

        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't even compile, will it?

Comment: @James_D  i know but what should i do ?

Comment: You can't create a `KeyValue` specifying two doubles. Don't you get a compile error that tells you that? You need a `WritableValue` - typically a `Property`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @James_D in fact scene doesn't have any  WritableValue

Comment: Well I know that. Your question title just says you want to change scenes. What is the timeline for?

Comment: @James_D Time line is for transition(having smooth change)

Comment: What does that mean? It looks like you are trying to animate the width of the scene? The scene always has the same width as the window containing it (less any window decorations, like window borders and title bar, etc). Do you want to animate the width of the stage?

Comment: @James_D somehow yes, i have two scene i want to change my scene by click on a button then having an smooth changing from one scene to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to animate the width of the stage holding your new scene, you can use a [`Transition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html):

```
public void signUpScene(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws IOException {
        Scene SignUpScene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sign up.fxml")),700,700);
        Main.pstage.setScene(SignUpScene);

        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0, 700);

        Transition animateStage = new Transition() {
            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
            }
            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double t) {
                Main.pstage.setWidth(t * 700.0);
            }
        };
        animateStage.play();
    }
}
```

Maybe a better approach would be to gradually reveal the new scene using a clip:

```
public void signUpScene(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sign up.fxml"));

        Scene SignUpScene = new Scene(root,700,700);
        Main.pstage.setScene(SignUpScene);

        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0, 700);
        Timeline animate = new Timeline(
           new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), 
               new KeyValue(clip.widthProperty(), 700.0));
        root.setClip(clip);
        // when animation finishes, remove clip:
        animate.setOnFinished(e -> root.setClip(null));
        animate.play();
    }
}
```